# ggplot: Fill small area under normal curve: remove "joining" area

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, area

I would like to fille a small area under a curve. However, the ribbon geoms join the two "parts" of the distribution.

```
library(tidyverse)
density(rnorm(1000, 0, 1)) %$%
  data.frame(x=x, y=y) %>%
  mutate(area = dplyr::between(x, 1.5, 2.6)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = x, ymin = 0, ymax = y, fill = area))
```

[image]

I believe one of the way of avoiding this behaviour would be to split the distribution into three different parts, and fill the two of them with the same colour. However, I am looking for a more neat and elegant way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the way the red ribbon gets interpolated across the blue region, where there are no red values so a straight line is drawn to the next red point. You can work around this by just plotting the whole ribbon first, not accounting for `area`, and then plotting the subset over the top:

```
library(tidyverse)
density(rnorm(1000, 0, 1)) %$%
    data.frame(x=x, y=y) %>%
    mutate(area = dplyr::between(x, 1.5, 2.6)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, ymin = 0, ymax = y)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(fill = "Outside")) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(fill = "Inside"), data = function(df) df %>% filter(area))
```

Result:

[image]